# Fade in background/div with title/div always visible on top

Tags: jquery, css, title, jquery-hover

I have some jQuery that fades in `.gridHover`. but it covers up `.title`.

I tried changing the z-index, but then the hover effect stops when hovering the title. I tried duplicating the title and fading that in as well, but it just doesn't work well and looks sloppy.

I would like to keep `.title` visible at all times (maybe change color on hover of `.gridHover`) and the hover effect always hover-able over the whole area of `.gridHover`.

Firstly, is that possible? Secondly, how? :)

### HTML

```
<div class="gridContainer" style="background-image: url('image.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: 50% 50%;">

     <div class="title">Title</div>

     <a href="#">
         <span class="gridHover"></span>
     </a>

</div>
```

### jQuery

```
// Grid Hover - Overlay ----------------//
$('.gridHover').each(function(index) {

    $(this).hover(
      function () {
        $(this).fadeTo(100, .85);
      },
      function () {
        $(this).fadeTo(400, 0);
      }
    );

});
```

### CSS

```
span.gridHover {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 11;
    background:#fff;
    opacity:0;
    padding-top: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

div.title {
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
    top: 50%;
    font-family: 'RockwellStd', georgia, serif;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 11;
}
```

Comment: You have z-index: 11 on both elements, so this can't work like expected. Change the z-index of the .title to something higher and it probably will work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, as I mentioned in the OP, when I raise the z-index, the title blocks some of the hover area, so it's not really a viable solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you aren't binding the hover event to the parent "gridContainer" element instead of the "gridHover?"

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the hover event changes the opacity of the element it's bound to, right? So, I want the `.gridContainer` to always show (it's the main image), then an overlay to fade in on hover. So the hover event needs to be acting on a separate element, again if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: The hover even does bind to your selector. However, you can still select it's children and run your animation relative to the "parent" selector. Instead of using `$(this).fadeTo(100, .85);` you should use `$(this).find('.gridHover').fadeTo(100, .85);`